# Client Server sockets - Non-blocking I/O

Tags: c, sockets

I cannot get my head around how to have non-blocking I/O. This is my current architecture:

**Server**

- Create server socket (`socket()`)
- `bind()` to IP on port number
- `listen()` for incoming connections
- Enter `while(1)` loop {

  - `accept()` incoming connection
  - Spawn (`fork()`) a new child process to handle `recv()`ing and `send()`ing

**Client**

- Create client socket (`socket()`)
- `connect()` client socket to server socket
- Enter `while(1)` loop {

  - `pipe()` to create pipe file descriptors for parent and child processes
  - Read user input from `stdin` (*ALWAYS* available i.e. not blocking)

    - Spawn (`fork()`) a new child process to handle the user input, `send()`ing and `recv()`ing to and from the server socket
    - Once output from the child process is ready, `write()` to the parent
  - parent `read()` output message from child and print to terminal *without blocking stdin*

What do I need to change? I just want to be able to type a message into the *client* terminal, have the client child process communicate with the server in the background, formatting the output and everything, and then once ready to output, it just outputs without blocking me from entering more requests in the *client* terminal.

For example if I were to ask the terminal to sleep for 10 seconds, and then return "I'm awake!" after that time had passed. I would be able to process other requests in the meantime without the *client* terminal just waiting.

```
Enter a command: sleep 10
Enter a command: sendfile text.txt
Enter a command: echo money
money
Enter a command: echo hello
hello
I'm awake!
Enter a command:
```

Comment: *Polling*? Through e.g. [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)? You can use that to poll multiple and different descriptors (sockets, pipes, standard input, etc.).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So I would use `select()` with an almost instant timeout for descriptors ready to write? Where would I put this in my **Client** architecture? Do I also need to remove the parent process's `read()` to avoid blocking there?

Comment: In the client there's no need for pipes or child-processes. Just a loop where you poll `STDIN_FILENO` and your socket with an infinite timeout. If you get input from standard input then read it and send through your socket and go back to polling. If you get input from the socket, read it and print, and go back to polling.

Comment: Also consider making the descriptors (both `STDIN_FILENO` and the socket) non-blocking, so it's easy to detect when there's nothing more to read from them (`read`/`recv` return `-1` with `errno` set to `EWOULDBLOCK`).